# C# Reading Stream

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I want to read a .txt file in C# but I will not read all the lines at the same time. For example, consider 500 lines of text file. I want a function to run 25 times and read 20 consecutive lines each time. In the first call of function, lines from 1 to 20 will be read, and second time it is called, 21-40 will be read.

Below simple code does this in c++ but I don't know how to achieve it in C#:

```
string readLines(ifstream& i)
{
     string totalLine="", line = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
          getline(i, line);

          totalLine += line;
     }
     return totalLine;
}

int main()
{

     // ...
     ifstream in;
     in.open(filename.c_str());
     while(true){
         string next20 = readLines(in);
         // so something with 20 lines.
     }
     // ...

}
```

Comment: [How to: Read Text from a File:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

Comment: The code you've given in C++ doesn't do that at all - it just loops reading *all* the lines. That's easy to do in C# too... `foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(...))`. The batching isn't too bad in C#...

Comment: That is just a quick example. What I meant by that is that if you put the while statement into a function and even if you prematurely quit reading file, it will continue where it left off.

Comment: @MertToka: That "quick example" doesn't demonstrate what you're trying to do then - it's basically not adding anything to the question.

Comment: That's definitely better - although `first20` is misleading given that it will only actually be the *first* 20 lines on the first iteration. `next20` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

There are various options here, but one simple approach would be:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("file.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        HandleLines(reader);
    }
}

...

private void HandleLines(TextReader reader)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null) // Handle the file ending early
        {
            // Process the line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If are trying to call `LineRead()` the *least number times possible* and you want *minimum memory usage* you could first index the lines in your file:

> 1. Parse the file one time and **Index** the position of each line in the `FileStream`.
> 2. Call **ReadLine()** only at the desired location.

eg:

```
// Parse the file
var indexes = new List<long>();
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("text.txt"))
{
    indexes.Add(fs.Position);
    int chr;
    while ((chr = fs.ReadByte()) != -1)
    {
        if (chr == '\n')
        {                        
            indexes.Add(fs.Position);
        }
    }
}

int minLine = 21;
int maxLine = 40;

// Read the line
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("text.txt"))
{
    for(int i = minLine ; i <= maxLine ; i++)
    {
        fs.Position = indexes[ i ];
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());

}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Batch() method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Batch(IEnumerable<string> input, int batchSize)
{
    int n = 0;
    var block = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var line in input)
    {
        block.AppendLine(line);

        if (++n != batchSize)
            continue;

        yield return block.ToString();
        block.Clear();
        n = 0;
    }

    if (n != 0)
        yield return block.ToString();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
string filename = "<Your filename goes here>";
var batches = Batch(File.ReadLines(filename), 20);

foreach (var block in batches)
{
    Console.Write(block);
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. GroupBy does not evaluate lazily, so this will greedily consume whole file

```
var twentyLineGroups = 
    File.ReadLines(somePath)
        .Select((line, index) => new {line, index})
        .GroupBy(x => x.index / 20)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.line));

foreach(IEnumerable<string> twentyLineGroup in twentyLineGroups)
{
    foreach(string line in twentyLineGroup)
    {
        //tada!
    }
}
```

Comment: So this code piece actually divides the lines by 20, then loops over lines while looping over the groups, right? I am very unfamiliar with the first statement's functions.